# pdfplumber extract_table omits data from cropped area, why?

Tags: python, pdfplumber

[image]I have used pdfplumber with perfect results but am stumped with this one. I want to extract the data from a table on a PDF page. I crop the data on the page to contain a table, set the vertical lines and extract_table fails to find the rightmost column. For comparison when I extract_text from the same cropped area it finds all the expected data. In the output below the 3rd VAT column is missing from the table lines.

```
import os, sys, pdfplumber
print('pdfplumber v.'+pdfplumber.__version__, \
        'Python v.'+str(sys.version_info.major)+'.'+\
          str(sys.version_info.minor),'\n')
vlines = [44.6, 95.65, 124.0, 186.35, 277.05, 322.4, 367.75, 421.6, \
          464.15, 506.7, 544.7539999999999]
boundingbox = (45, 285, 550, 350)
pdf = pdfplumber.open('test.pdf')
for pageno, page in enumerate(pdf.pages,1):
    if pageno == 4:
        pagecropped = page.crop(boundingbox, strict=True)
        textlines = pagecropped.extract_text()
        textlines = textlines.split('\n')
        for textline in textlines:
            print('text line:',textline)
        print()
        tablelines = pagecropped.extract_table(table_settings=\
           {"vertical_strategy":"explicit",\
            "explicit_vertical_lines":vlines,\
            "horizontal_strategy": "text",\
            "snap_tolerance": 5})
        for tableline in tablelines:
            print('table line:', tableline)

pdfplumber v.0.11.0 Python v.3.12 

text line: UK calls
text line: Date Time Phone number Destination Duration Charged Included? VAT VAT VAT
text line: hh:mm:ss hh:mm:ss ex rate inc
text line: Mon 20 Jul 13:44 01435883510 Landline 00:00:48 00:01:00 Yes £0.000 20% £0.000
text line: Mon 20 Jul 13:45 07818648038 Vodafone mobile 00:00:04 00:01:00 Yes £0.000 20% £0.000
text line: Wed 29 Jul 08:57 121 Voicemail 00:00:57 00:01:00 Yes £0.000 20% £0.000
text line: Fri 31 Jul 18:16 01509633033 Landline 00:00:57 00:01:00 Yes £0.000 20% £0.000

table line: ['UK calls', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
table line: ['Date', 'Time', 'Phone number', 'Destination', 'Duration', 'Charged', 'Included?', 'VAT', 'VAT']
table line: ['', '', '', '', 'hh:mm:ss', 'hh:mm:ss', '', 'ex', 'rate']
table line: ['Mon 20 Jul', '13:44', '01435883510', 'Landline', '00:00:48', '00:01:00', 'Yes', '£0.000', '20%']
table line: ['Mon 20 Jul', '13:45', '07818648038', 'Vodafone mobile', '00:00:04', '00:01:00', 'Yes', '£0.000', '20%']
table line: ['Wed 29 Jul', '08:57', '121', 'Voicemail', '00:00:57', '00:01:00', 'Yes', '£0.000', '20%']
table line: ['Fri 31 Jul', '18:16', '01509633033', 'Landline', '00:00:57', '00:01:00', 'Yes', '£0.000', '20%']
```